# ProgressDialog not showing up - Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to display progress dialog in ACTION_UP, for some weird reason it's not working, I don't see any error in the logs, everything in the ACTION_UP block is working except for the progress dialog? anyone has any idea what's going on?

I even added Toast to test it and it works just fine...

```
button.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            //works here
           //progress = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Processing...","Preparing your file", true);
         } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP  ) {

            Toast toast;
            duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
            toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();//this work and the toast is getting displayed

            progress = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Processing...","Preparing your file", true);

        }
        return true;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason sometimes progressDialog wont show if your are calling show if the main thread i don't know why but i run into the same issue a time ago my work arround was to call show using a handler and a runnable

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
             progressDialog.show();
        }
},100);
```

Comment: Or you can use the awesome material library https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Comment: Glad that i could help ;)

Comment: Because progress dialog when shown block the main thread so it can leak memory

Answer (score 0):

I tend to show dialog notifications like the code below where you would put subShowdialog(); where you are showing your Toast. Should work.

```
private void subShowdialog() { 
    final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show( 
            context, "Processing...","Preparing your file", true); 

    new Thread() { 
        public void run() { 
            try { 
                sleep(1000);
                //Start whatever action here
                progDailog.dismiss(); 
            } catch (Exception e) { 
            } 

        } 
    }.start(); 
}
```

Comment: Oops, I see I posted my answer after others had already added a correct answer (teach me to start an answer whilst I make a coffee).